# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Can't call rollback when autocommit=true

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

Im using Jboss5.0 with mysql in my application. and there will be lot of concurrent actions and DB contains considerably lot of records. 
this error is coming frequently.. every now and then.

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
 Can't call rollback when
 autocommit=true    at
 com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:888)
    at
 com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.rollback(Connection.java:5192)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection.rollback(LocalManagedConnection.java:97)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener.tidyup(TxConnectionManager.java:783)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.returnManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:453)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener.connectionClosed(TxConnectionManager.java:734)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.closeHandle(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:362)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.close(WrappedConnection.java:155)
```

can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5370911

Comment: thanks. if i set auto commit false for a whole , will it affect any non transactional updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you are attempting to call rollback when auto commit is turned on, or you're using MyISAM type tables in your database which do not support transactions (and the ability to rollback).

Judging by the stacktrace, a transaction to the database is failing and in an attempt to create an SQLException and rollback the transaction, this exception is occurring. Unless there's more to the exception (like an indication as to where in *your* code the exception is being fired), then I would hazard a guess that it's due to MyISAM tables.

Comment: im using innodb and it support transactions. im having both transactional  and non-transactional queries.

Comment: @Tamizh, are you calling rollback() in your code and if so, have you tried disabling auto commit before doing so?

Comment: yes whenever i use transactions i first set autocommit false.
 and now i found its coming as WARN in jboss log file instead ERROR. so actually this is a WARNING when connections lost or blinking for long time i guess