# Rollback behaviour when commit failed due to no connection

Tags: java, jdbc, eclipselink, rollback, hikaricp

Currently, we are using HikariCP to manage our connection pool.

Given the below mentioned code snippet, we are facing the following problem:

```
try{
    txn.begin(); 
    entityManager.persist(someEntity);
    txn.commit();// Line 1
} catch(Throwable tx ){
   if(txn.isActive()){
    txn.rollback(); //Line 2
   }
}
```

EntityManager tries to commit- for that it needs a connection from the HikariCP. Hikari times out, and since we didn't get any database connection, this leads to exception. Now when transaction is attempted to be rollbacked, the rollback sequence attempts to get a connection again-

1. If connection is not found, it fails again,
2. If a connection is found from the Pool, it is used. By default the connection is in autocommit= true mode, so the rollback fails and the Pool marks the connection as broken, because the expected state of the connection when rollback happens is autocommit=0.

This is weird, because one would assume that rollback should happen on the same connection as the commit was attempted; if connection was not found, there should be no rollback attempted. however this is not what is happening. This is causing healthy connections to be marked as broken, and this cycle repeats in most APIs whenever there is stress on the Pool.

We are using EclipseLink version 2.5.2, but this problem is there even in the latest version. I could trace it back to this part of the rollback sequence in DatasourceAccessor.java:

```
 public synchronized void incrementCallCount(AbstractSession session) {
    this.callCount++;

    if (this.callCount == 1) {
        // If the login is null, then this accessor has never been connected.
        if (this.login == null) {
            throw DatabaseException.databaseAccessorNotConnected();
        }

        // If the connection is no longer connected, it may have timed out.
        if (this.datasourceConnection != null) {
            if (shouldCheckConnection && !isConnected()) {
                if (this.isInTransaction) {
                    throw DatabaseException.databaseAccessorNotConnected();
                } else {
                    reconnect(session);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If ExternalConnectionPooling is used, the connection can be re-established.
            if (this.usesExternalConnectionPooling) {
                reconnect(session); //Why reconnect?
                session.postAcquireConnection(this);
                currentSession = session;
            } else {
                throw DatabaseException.databaseAccessorNotConnected();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IMHO while doing rollback new connection should not be acquired. It makes no sense. Am I missing something?

Java: 1.8.0_91
Hikari: 3.0.1
MySQL Connector: 8.0.11
Eclipselink: 2.5.2/2.7 both tried.
Engine: Innodb.

Edit: Stacktrace added as requested:

08 May 2018 13:18:39,468 -[Thread-159847]-[1161705814:77]-  WARN - ProxyConnection.checkException(156) - HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@47f8b848 marked as 
broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Can't call rollback when autocommit=true
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:5078)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:361)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicRollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1700)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.rollbackTransaction(DatasourceAccessor.java:688)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.rollbackTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:1691)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicRollbackTransaction(AbstractSession.java:779)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.basicRollbackTransaction(ClientSession.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.rollbackTransaction(AbstractSession.java:3795)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.rollbackTransaction(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4670)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.rollbackTransaction(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.rollbackTransaction(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1480)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
        at com.paytm.wallet.dao.domain.UserBeneficiaryManager.updateBenefeciaryDetails(UserBeneficiaryManager.java:81)
        at com.paytm.wallet.web.wrapper.business.impl.UserBeneficiaryHelper.addBeneficary(UserBeneficiaryHelper.java:247)
        at com.paytm.wallet.web.concurrent.AddBeneficiaryThread.run(AddBeneficiaryThread.java:36)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: incrementCallCount is generic and used for any calls, not just rollback. Show the stack from the initial exception.  While it seems a bug, the context of the original exception is needed to see why the transaction is showing as active and allowing you to call rollback at all.

Comment: Have added stack trace. Please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Can't call rollback when autocommit=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911968/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-cant-call-rollb)

Comment: Hmm..yes. Similar problem. That answer does not directly address the concern about the rollback on a new connection, though. We are not using MyISAM.

Comment: @Chris-- can you please check the stacktrace?